# QMediaPlayer.setPosition not working after setSource in PySide6

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74344154/play-multiple-sounds-with-same-timestamp/) I want to switch music with playing position unchanged and the answer works quite well for PyQt5. Now I'd like to transfer my app to PySide6 due to more friendly license. But it is not working anymore. Here is my code which is derived from PySide's official [example](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_multimedia__player.html)

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QStandardPaths, Qt, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QKeySequence, QScreen
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QFileDialog,
                               QMainWindow, QSlider, QStyle, QToolBar)
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import (QAudio, QAudioOutput, QMediaFormat,
                                  QMediaPlayer)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        url1 = QUrl.fromLocalFile('path/to/music1.mp3')
        url2 = QUrl.fromLocalFile('path/to/music2.mp3')
        self._playlist = [url1, url2]
        self._playlist_index = 0
        self._audio_output = QAudioOutput()
        self._player = QMediaPlayer()
        self._player.setAudioOutput(self._audio_output)
        self._player.setSource(self._playlist[self._playlist_index])

        tool_bar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(tool_bar)

        style = self.style()
        icon = QIcon.fromTheme("media-playback-start.png",
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self._play_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Play")
        self._play_action.triggered.connect(self._player.play)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme("media-skip-backward-symbolic.svg",
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSkipBackward))
        self._previous_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Previous")
        self._previous_action.triggered.connect(self.previous_clicked)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme("media-seek-backward-symbolic.svg",
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSeekBackward))
        self._previous_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Backward")
        self._previous_action.triggered.connect(self.backward_clicked)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme("media-playback-pause.png",
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        self._pause_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Pause")
        self._pause_action.triggered.connect(self._player.pause)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme("media-seek-forward-symbolic.svg",
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSeekForward))
        self._next_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Forward")
        self._next_action.triggered.connect(self.forward_clicked)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme("media-skip-forward-symbolic.svg",
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaSkipForward))
        self._next_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Next")
        self._next_action.triggered.connect(self.next_clicked)

        icon = QIcon.fromTheme("media-playback-stop.png",
                               style.standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaStop))
        self._stop_action = tool_bar.addAction(icon, "Stop")
        self._stop_action.triggered.connect(self._ensure_stopped)

    @Slot()
    def _ensure_stopped(self):
        if self._player.playbackState() != QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            self._player.stop()

    @Slot()
    def previous_clicked(self):
        if self._playlist_index > 0:
            self._playlist_index -= 1
            position = self._player.position()
            print('position before change source', position)
            self._player.setSource(self._playlist[self._playlist_index])
            self._player.play()
            self._player.setPosition(position)
            print('position after change source', self._player.position())

    @Slot()
    def next_clicked(self):
        if self._playlist_index < len(self._playlist) - 1:
            self._playlist_index += 1
            position = self._player.position()
            print('position before change source', position)
            self._player.setSource(self._playlist[self._playlist_index])
            self._player.play()
            self._player.setPosition(position)
            print('position after change source', self._player.position())

    @Slot()
    def backward_clicked(self):
        self._player.setPosition(self._player.position() - 5000)

    @Slot()
    def forward_clicked(self):
        self._player.setPosition(self._player.position() + 5000)

    @Slot("QMediaPlayer::PlaybackState")
    def update_buttons(self, state):
        media_count = len(self._playlist)
        self._play_action.setEnabled(media_count > 0 and
                                     state != QMediaPlayer.PlayingState)
        self._pause_action.setEnabled(state == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState)
        self._stop_action.setEnabled(state != QMediaPlayer.StoppedState)
        self._previous_action.setEnabled(self._playlist_index > 0)
        self._next_action.setEnabled(self._playlist_index < len(self._playlist) - 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

It seems that I don't need `pause()` and `play()` before and after setting the new position and this works fine in `forward_clicked()` and `backward_clicked()`, but it doesn't work after `setSource()` to switch music content. From printed message I can see that

```
position before change source 1910
position after change source 0
```

I found that `self._player.isSeekable() = False` during `next_clicked()` and `previous_clicked()`. Qt's official [documents](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer.html#PySide6.QtMultimedia.PySide6.QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.isSeekable) states that the status of this property may change across the life time of the `QMediaPlayer` object. Why?

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
I've tried the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73590441/qmediaplayer-setposition-qtpython) which also failed. Here's two simple examples based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232236/how-qmediaplayer-setposition-works-for-mp3/63238176), btw I work only on `.wav` files, loading it can be relatively fast.

According to [@musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante)'s answer:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QAudioOutput
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, Qt


class Player(QMediaPlayer):
    _delayedPos = 0

    def setPosition(self, pos):
        super().setPosition(pos)
        if pos and not self.isSeekable():
            self._delayedPos = pos
            try:
                # ensure that the connection is done only once
                self.seekableChanged.connect(self.delaySetPosition, Qt.UniqueConnection)
            except:
                pass
        else:
            self._delayedPos = 0

    def delaySetPosition(self, seekable):
        if seekable:
            self.setPosition(self._delayedPos)
        try:
            # just to be safe, in case the media changes before the previous one
            # becomes seekable
            self.seekableChanged.disconnect(self.delaySetPosition)
        except:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    audio_output = QAudioOutput()
    player = Player()
    player.setAudioOutput(audio_output)
    media_content = QUrl.fromLocalFile(r'path\to\music.wav')
    player.setSource(media_content)
    player.setPosition(10000)
    player.play()

    app.exec()
```

According to [@Geneviève M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11491671/genevi%c3%a8ve-m)'s answer:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QAudioOutput
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl


def update_position(status):
    if (status == QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia):
        player.setPosition(10000)
        player.play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    audio_output = QAudioOutput()
    player = QMediaPlayer()
    player.setAudioOutput(audio_output)
    media_content = QUrl.fromLocalFile(r'path\to\music.wav')
    player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(update_position)
    player.setSource(media_content)

    app.exec()
```

These two answers work well for PyQt5 but not for PySide6.

Comment: The status may change because the media loading is asynchronous (consider a network url for a media file: it might be not available, or the content could not be seekable). Please show us how you actually tried the solution mentioned at the end of your post.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for your reply! I've also read your answer before and I understand it's asynchronous due to loading data from disk or decoding. I've update my question including the solution I tried. Please have a look.